# Comparison of two 2D datasets of different length

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance

I have a dataset containing atmospheric methane concentrations where each data point has two dimensions: one for measured concentrations and the other for modeled concentrations. The dataset is divided into two subsets based on daytime and nighttime timestamp. My goal is to investigate whether there are systematic deviations between the daytime and nighttime modeling results (e.g. if nighttime modeling has one-sided bias towards over- or underestimation of the measurements OR if this bias SIGNIFICANTLY more or less pronounced compared to the daytime modeling).

Dataset Structure:

- daytime_data/nighttime_data: 2D array of measured and modeled hourly methane
  concentrations during the daytime/nighttime.

Approach:
I plan to compare the differences between the measured and modeled concentrations for each subset. However, the daytime and nighttime subsets have different lengths.

I am seeking advice on how to appropriately analyze this dataset to address the following questions:

1. How can I statistically test if there are significant differences
   between daytime and nighttime modeling results?
2. Should I use a specific statistical test, such as the
   Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon test, considering the unequal sample sizes and
   non-normally distributed data (with relatively small sample size)?
3. Are there any other statistical methods better suited to handle this
   type of analysis?

Here are few additional notes:

- My first idea was to just do a linear regression for each set and
  just compare the slopes of the fits (the y-axis offsets are usually
  small). But it is hard to say in this case if the slopes are
  significantly different.
- I don't really care in this case if the modeled results are
  "correct", only if there is any systematic difference between daytime
  and nighttime model behaviour. Thus I though I could flatten the
  array and build the 1D difference between model and measurements (for
  daytime and nighttime separately) and apply any statistical approach
  to this array. Are there any potential problems with this?
- If it is of any importance: the daytime set has about 15 entries and
  nighttime about 60 entries (asymmetric daytime/nighttime classification). The concentration values are ranging
  from 1900 to 2100 ppb.

I would appreciate any insights, suggestions, or Python code examples that could help me conduct the appropriate statistical analysis for my research.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1. How are the modeled values obtained? Are they based on some data? The same data? Different data? 2. Ignoring issues arising from item 1, the values would presumably be paired, so a KS test (comparing their marginal distributions) would presumably not be relevant.  The first thing I'd probably think about would be a Tukey mean/difference plot, but it sounds like you might seek something more like the kind of analysis done in calibration (which would typically involve regression)

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for getting back to me! 
1. Modeled and observed data are completely independent from each other. The observations were obtained directly from measurement systems installed on the site. The modeled data was obtained using emission data and transport models. 
2. Yeah, one of the used methods is linear regression between modeled and observed data. I then compare the slope of daytime and nighttime trying to deduce if the are the same. But we have only small amount of data points so regression id somewhat susceptible for the outliers on the edges. Thats why I was thought about KS.