# Discrete P-values in Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test with Small Sample Sizes

Tags: python, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I'm facing an issue while conducting the Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS) test with two datasets of different sizes: 84 and 28 samples. I got these sets from normal distribution. I've noticed that the calculated p-values seem to cluster around certain values, leaving gaps in between. After some research, I came across the concept of "Knuth's Rule correction," which is suggested to address this problem by making the distribution of p-values more continuous and that it should be applied if one have small sets. However, I'm uncertain about how to properly apply Knuth's Rule correction and whether it's appropriate in my case. Am I goning in the right direction with it?

Are there any other considerations or techniques I should be aware of when dealing with discrete p-values in the context of the KS test?

I would greatly appreciate your insights and guidance!

Here is the picture with discrete p-values over run number:
[image: Discrete p-values]

Here is the code that I have used:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp

# Parameters for the normal distribution
mu = 0       # Mean
sigma = 1    # Standard deviation

# Number of iterations
num_iterations = 1000

# Lengths of the two sets
n1 = 84
n2 = 28
    
# Perform KS test multiple times
p_values = []

for i in range(num_iterations):
     
    # Generate random data from normal distribution
    data1 = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, int(n1))
    data2 = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, int(n2))

    # Perform KS test
    ks_statistic, p_value = ks_2samp(data1, data2)

    p_values.append(p_value)
```

Comment: I would look into the implementation. It may be binning in order to compute probabilities.

Comment: @Galen The two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic is inherently discrete; since ecdfs are scaled counts, it's a scaled (absolute) difference in two counts at a particular location on the real line.

Comment: @Glen_b Oh that's right. Sorry, I was thinking of something else related to binning before plugging probabilities into the Kullback-Leibler divergence.

Comment: @Maksym I don't see any way to make a discrete distribution continuous\*. Do you have a link that explains what Knuth's Rule correction might be?  $\:$ \*(except by the usual randomized test approach, which would often be seen as problematic, since different people would come to different decisions on the same data while using the same significance level)

Comment: I Googled and the only thing I found for Knuth's rule correction was this post.  There is a "Knuth's rule" for the number of bins in a histogram, but I don't think that's relevant.   Like Galen, I see no sensible way to do this.

Comment: Why are you using p values from a KS test anyway? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The standard technique of coping with discrete p-values (which indicates the test statistic is discrete) is to conduct a randomized test.  That's uncommon and isn't especially necessary in this application.

Comment: @PeterFlom Maybe I am going something completely weird...Originally, I was truing to to compare the distribution of the p-values from KS from my experimental set-up (I have many set pairs with 84 and 24 entries) with the one from this 'Monte Carlo' like approach. From the code above I would expect p-values uniformly distributed over the range from 0 to 1. Now I am trying to understand if this discrete nature comes from KS or from Python. But as I can see from the answer from Glen_b the two sample KS is discrete and there is not much one can do about it.

Comment: @Glen_b Unfortunately, I don't have any additional information on 'Knut's Rule' and now I am suspecting it is not real at all-- A fellow student has suggested to use it but couldn't properly explain what it was. I thought I was missing something.

Comment: If you have time could you look at my original problem comparing two data sets? 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/622217/comparison-of-two-2d-datasets-of-different-length

I decided to use KS test on the difference between modeled and measured and then use KS to determine if night time and day time are different (with significance of 0.05). Does it make any sense?

Comment: The only Knuth's rule that's remotely related that I've heard of is Knuth, K.H. “Optimal Data-Based Binning for Histograms”. arXiv:0605197, 2006 ... but that's not relevant here